# Unlock android phone from PC

Tags: lock-screens, password, locked-out

I need to move some data from my HTC one m8 to a *Samsung Galaxy S8.* The only problem is that the HTC's touch screen does not work so I cannot unlock it (it's locked with a PIN). I don't have a keyboard adapter for this phones port so I cannot plug a keyboard or mouse into it. I can plug it into my laptop so can I unlock it from there?

Comment: That'll be a bit harder. I don't know which method works, but our [locked-out tag-wiki](/tags/locked-out/info) should be a good starter. Good luck!

Answer (score -1):

I found a solution after all, you have to keep pressing the volume down button so that the phone does not lock itself and shut the screen off. This gives more time to mash the screen to enter the pin.

The screen barley works but sometimes if I press hard it registers it.

After it was unlocked I again used the volume down button in order to stop the phone locking after a few minutes of inactivity. I then plugged it into my laptop and moved the data from the phone to my desktop.

I could have disabled a pin or disabled auto screen lock in the settings but the screen was just too messed up so certain on screen buttons did not work.

I still need to somehow back up my scribble app notes. The back button in the app does not work and clicking the back button next to the home panel closes the app rather than closing the text editor and going back to the main screen where all my notes are.